# How does the scoring system work for the credits game?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I've played through SSBU's Classic Mode maybe two dozen times with various characters, and each time I've played through the Credits Game, where you have to shoot at the credits (plus a handful of polygonal enemies) as they scroll across the screen.

I consistently score between 1.6 - 1.68 million, but there doesn't seem to be any pattern to whether I score higher or lower on any given run. I've had runs where I've been hit by multiple enemies and missed a few names due to being stunned, and yet still scored more points than in runs where I didn't get hit at all and (as far as I can tell) hit every single name and enemy.

To add to my confusion, the high-score for the SSBU credits game on Cyberscore is roughly 1.86 million. I cannot fathom where people are getting those extra 180,000 points from, but there has to be some aspect of the scoring system that I'm not aware of.

So: **how does the scoring system work for SSBU's credits game?** What methods can I use to reliably obtain a higher score?

<sub>I'm aware that scoring anything beyond 1.5 million doesn't really matter, but my competitive streak has kicked in and just won't let this go.</sub>

Comment: I would recommend doing 2-player if you want to try to get everything. The second player can either act as backup or use larger bullets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend not using the charge function where you can hold A for the Super Scope to charge a massive bullet, but instead to just go back and forth across the screen and spamming A. That is how I got 1.86 million, the maximum score in the credits. Other than that, there is really no trick to winning.

Comment: I didn't even know you *could* hold A to charge a bigger bullet. I've been weaving back and forth and spamming bullets this whole time. If there's really nothing else I can do to improve my score, then I guess that's fair enough.

Comment: Also, you should avoid the enemies. This is because they disable your blaster for a few secs.